# Combine rows to remove nulls while using latest value based on time

Tags: postgresql, group-by, query, distinct

I have a table that has multiple rows associated with each ID but sometimes containing differing info:

```
Key, ID,  Name,  Title,  Time
4,   AA,  Abe,   NULL,   2018-01-05
3,   BB,  NULL,  Mrs,    2018-01-04
2,   AA,  NULL,  Mr,     2018-01-03
1,   BB,  Cat,   Ms,     2018-01-02
```

Some of the fields are Nulls, some of the row have differing info for the same columns and ID but there will always be an ID and a timestamp.

I want a query where I can squash Nulls but when there are multiple differing fields choose the latest one. Something like this:

```
Result = 
ID,  Name,  Title,  Time
AA,  Abe,   Mr,     2018-01-05
BB,  Cat,   Mrs,    2018-01-04
```

I have something using "SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, name, title)" but I'm missing the next step so it's not working.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/72ba3/1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
     , SUBSTRING(MAX(time || name) FROM 11) "name"
     , SUBSTRING(MAX(time || title) FROM 11) title
     , MAX(time) "time"
FROM test_table
GROUP BY id
```

The `FROM 11` part extracts the data (`name` or `title`) from the concatenated aggregate values. First 10 characters is the date (`time` column).

Comment: @RedM query refined

Comment: What does the "from 11" bit do?

Comment: @RedM Function extracts data (`name`, `title`) field from aggregate. First 10 symbols is date (`time` field).

Comment: Hmm.. somebody downvoted the answer without both reason explaination and posting another, the better, answer. Modest, maybe...